# Specify Global Time Range on Azure DevOps API Calls

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the Azure DevOps API to put together a report of build metrics. I am looking for a way to add a global time range query parameter to my calls, so that I am only querying items that occur within the range of time *x* and time *y*.

It appears some specific calls contain a query parameter such as a "creationDate" or "startTime"; however I am unable to find a way to *globally* limit the date range of API calls I make. I am using a large selection of REST endpoints and many either do not contain a time range query parameter or use a different implementation method to accomplish the same thing.

In short, I am looking for a way to **globally** limit the Azure DevOps REST API with either a query parameter or an API key setting to return results within a specific range. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible out of the box. And it wouldn't be possible without modifying your code. What you need is to build a kind of wrapper around your http calls and add parameters defined somewhere else globally. But this is directly related to the language you use to perform http calls.

Comment: @pirateofebay `querying items that occur within the range of time x and time y` What behavior does the "occur" specifically refer to here (create, change or something else)? `Global Time Range` specifically refers to what time range? Can you give a detailed explanation? So that we can better understand your needs.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I am making GET requests against API endpoints including _apis/pipelines and _apis/build/builds. I am looking for a way to specify a time range such as "get all builds that ran within the last week" or "get all pipelines created within the last month" without modifying my code to parse these elements from each response. I know some APIs have a query parameter or some other mechanism that allows you to specify a date range. Unfortunately it looks like this may not be possible out of the box as mentioned by Krzysztof.

Comment: @pirateofebay Yes, there is currently no out-of-the-box method to achieve this demand. If the below answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to specify a time range such as "get all builds
> that ran within the last week" or "get all pipelines created within
> the last month" without modifying my code to parse these elements from
> each response.

If so, agree with Krzysztof Madej,  if the rest api does not provide parameters to specify the date range, there should be no out-of-the-box method to achieve this demand.

The [Builds-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api provides parameters such as `maxTime`, `minTime` to specify the date range, while the [Pipelines-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api does not provide such parameters to specify the date range.

[image]

So, if you don’t want to modify the code to parse these elements from response, I think this is currently impossible.